# What are the individual probabilities after √SWAP gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

Say, qubit $\left|a\right\rangle = \alpha_1|0\rangle + \beta_1|1\rangle$ and $|b\rangle = \alpha_2|0\rangle + \beta_2|1\rangle$.

After $\sqrt{\text{SWAP}}$(a,b) what are new probability amplitudes of $a$ and $b$ in terms of $\alpha_1,\, \alpha_2,\, \beta_1,\, \beta_2$?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! It is preferable that you use [MathJax](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49) to typeset your posts. Review [How to write a good question?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370). I've [edit]ed the question on your behalf, this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overall state of the input is $|a\rangle|b\rangle$, which we can represent as:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c} \alpha_1\alpha_2 \\ \alpha_1\beta_2 \\ \beta_1\alpha_2 \\ \beta_1\beta_2 \end{array}\right)
$$
We apply the square root of swap gate (note that there are different ways that this matrix could be written ),
$$
\sqrt{\text{SWAP}}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0                    & 0                    & 0 \\
0 & e^{i\pi/4}/\sqrt{2}  & e^{-i\pi/4}/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\
0 & e^{-i\pi/4}/\sqrt{2} & e^{i\pi/4}/\sqrt{2}  & 0 \\
0 & 0                    & 0                    & 1
\end{array}\right).
$$
Hence, we're after the calculation
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & e^{i\pi/4}/\sqrt{2} & e^{-i\pi/4}/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\
0 & e^{-i\pi/4}/\sqrt{2} & e^{i\pi/4}/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} \alpha_1\alpha_2 \\ \alpha_1\beta_2 \\ \beta_1\alpha_2 \\ \beta_2\beta_2 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\alpha_1\alpha_2 \\ e^{i\pi/4}(\alpha_1\beta_2-i\beta_1\alpha_2)/\sqrt{2} \\ e^{-i\pi/4}(\alpha_1\beta_2+i\beta_1\alpha_2)/\sqrt{2} \\ \beta_1\beta_2
\end{array}\right).
$$
Converting this back to Dirac notation gives us the final answer
$$\alpha_1\alpha_2|00\rangle+\frac{e^{i\pi/4}}{\sqrt{2}}(\alpha_1\beta_2-i\beta_1\alpha_2)|01\rangle+ \frac{e^{-i\pi/4}}{\sqrt{2}}(\alpha_1\beta_2+i\beta_1\alpha_2)|10\rangle+\beta_1\beta_2|11\rangle.
$$
Note that the probability amplitudes of each term are joint probability amplitudes of the whole system. As a general rule, you cannot separate this state into (state of a)$\otimes$(state of b), and therefore cannot identify individual probability amplitudes for each system.

Perhaps I could also suggest a bit of a notational change? If you want to refer to the two qubits as $a$ and $b$, do not also refer to the states of the two qubits as $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$, as that's only likely to lead to confusion when the states change.

Answer (score 2):

Just apply corresponding [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Square_root_of_Swap_gate_(%E2%88%9ASWAP)) of this gate on the vector 
$$ |a\rangle |b\rangle = \alpha_1\alpha_2|00\rangle + \alpha_1\beta_2|01\rangle + \beta_1\alpha_2|10\rangle + \beta_1\beta_2|11\rangle $$

Note that in general the resulting state will be entangled. Hence every qubit individually will be in the mixed state.